# How can I move my GitHub fork and then work on the current master?

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase, git-fork

I contribute to an open source project on GitHub but my branch has fallen way behind due to some changes I made not being pulled into the master branch by the owner of the project. I want to move the changes I've made to another branch so I can reference them, but then and then pull down a new fork of the current master branch of the project so I can work on that.

Comment: Create a branch from your current master and push it. Then go back to master, reset --hard to upstream/master, and push --force. And next time, don't ever implement a fix or feature on master. Start by creating a branch, and work in that branch. That way you can always keep master in sync.

Comment: This question should be asked at the Github customer service department, not on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: that did it - thanks!

Comment: @jagb no. It's a git question, and doesn't have much to do with github.

Comment: @JBNizet May be but I believe it's a question for github that can be found in their FAQ, not for Stack Overflow as it's an issue at github and not a coding question, just a question on how to ...  github... However, I posted an answer and a comment as the OP is new on here and I hope he will take some time to read the "How to ask" in the help section to learn more on how to use Stack Overflow..  I know I should not answer this kind of questions but I just wanted to help the new Stack Overflow users...  Have a nice day!

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer that appears to completely misunderstand the question?

Answer (score -4):

If nothing is working for you and you're not able to do it the way it should be possible:

[Transferring a repository owned by your personal account](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/)

[Moving a repository from GitHub.com to GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.2/admin/articles/moving-a-repository-from-github-com-to-github-enterprise/)

you might want to contact the [Github Customer Support](https://github.com/contact) and ask them for help, you can find their contact form [here](https://github.com/contact)